Shed Framing Lumber
Framing a 12x8 shed on a concrete slab I poured earlier this week. Thinking about using premium 2x4 Doug fir green for walls. Is this a mistake?  It is 25% of the cost of KD-HT.
Will use PT for the bottom plates.

KD-HT = Kiln-dried heat treated; PT = pressure treated.

Eh, it's a shed, not something fancy.
Just get it all framed quickly, before your green 2x4s can turn into pretzels. Once they are held in place by the building structure they can't go too far out of whack while they dry.
A shed is not generally a place where some slight changes as it dries will be a big deal. I have built sheds using rough green lumber as framing and siding.

If it is truly a premium grade Doug fir, straight grained, there should be no issue at ll with timing. That grade of fir is some really good stuff KD or green. If it is rough sawn, splinters are a bear, and the dimensions may be different than your plate material. Just hold everything to consistently to one side of the plate

Even good stuff can warp badly if it sits in a pile, wet lumber on one side and dry sunny weather on the other, IME. Carefully spaced with stickers (lumber sense of sticker) it should air-dry no problem, but that involves building a stack properly. Turning it into a frame also allows it to dry from all sides, so...

Fir 2x4s should be suitable for shed construction. I guess it largely depends on codes and whether the shed will be a one storey structure, or a two story one.
